# Is there any method to calculate number of paragraph in text file?

Tags: java, file

I am trying to calculate number of paragraph in a text file, but not able to get , whatever i tried is

```
FileReader fr=new FileReader(new File(path));
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

            String str=br.readLine();

                    String str1="";
            int i=0;

            while(str!=null)
            {           
                i++;
                            str1+=str;
                System.out.println(""+str);

                str=br.readLine();
            }

tried to separate str1 

 using :    "\t\n"  separator
 using :    "\t"    separator
```

,I googled but couldn't find solution for this problem , pls any body help here.

Edited Here:

```
Sample Text.
```

[image]

[image]

End of Paragraph shown in the Red Round

[image]

Edited Again Here as Asked by Anirudh:

```
try
        {
            FileReader fr=new FileReader(new File("C:/srivatLog/DataSet/a.txt"));
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

            String str=br.readLine();
            int count=0;
            while(str!=null)
            {
                String[] str1=str.split("^\\s+");               
                if(str1.length>1)
                {
                    count++;
                }


                str=br.readLine();
            }

            System.out.println(""+count);

            br.close();
            fr.close();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: What separates one paragraph from the next, in your file format?

Comment: Paragraphs are usually limited by a blank line.  So if you do a readLine and the line length is zero that's the end of the paragraph.  Of course there is some subtly to it for counting documents with zero paragraphs or one

Comment: @Erwin My file is simple text file , and i need to find number of paragraph, in this file.

Comment: @Vorsprung ,Thanks for reply but i dont have any line with zero length in my documents. This document comes from a pdf or doc or docx file which is converted to .txt format for java readability, so couldn't find any line with zero length.

Comment: So you just need to count the number of lines in the file.

Comment: @Azeem Thanks for reply, I have edited my question, pls see there, as i said it comes from pdf or doc or docx file so difficult to count the paragraphs from this file for me.

Comment: For Windows: `str1 += str + "\r\n";`. Best use a StringBuilder which is tremendously faster: `StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder(); ...; str1.append(str).append("\r\n"); ... str1.toString();`. `"\r\n"` = Carriage Return + Line Feed chars.

Answer (score 0):

If one paragraph is separated from the next using a blank line, you can use the regex `^\s*$` to count for blank lines between other lines and calculate the number of paragraphs as the number of blank lines between two normal lines + 1.

Edited:

The paragraphs start with a little indentation, while the lines within the paragraph start at the beginning of the line. So read each line and use the regex `^\\s+` to check if the line starts with a an indentation and count the number of lines that match the regex to find the number of paragraphs.

Comment: my file doesn't contains blank line, it comes from pdf or doc or docx file.

Comment: so, what does separate the paragraphs? Can you post a sample text from the file you are trying to read?

Comment: i couldnt paste full file ,i have edited my question with some sample text, like wise only my text file is arranged.

Comment: but my text file is formatted like this only, i have some bunch of line in one paragraph and another paragraph starts at new line only, with some bunch of line and so on., that what i can observe in text file.

Comment: regex `^\\s+` will check if the str has one or more spaces at the beginning. The `split()` method removes the provided regex, and hence if there were spaces at the beginning or not, the returned array would have only one value and hence your count will never get increased. Use `str.matches("^\\s+")`, and also have a look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html for a good tutorial on how to use regex in java.

Comment: Using str.matches("^\\s+"), shows me only count=1, but file contains many paragraphs. i will also refer given site for more expression matches.

Comment: Last time when you posted the sample text, they had indentation at the start of a paragraph, but the image you have posted now don't have them. For the image that you have posted, I don't think there could be a definite way to find the number of paragraphs, but if as shown in the image, all the paragraphs end with some space at the end of the last line of the paragraphs, you could change the regex to `\\s+$`.

Answer (score 0):

even i couldnt find the solution for this problem from anywhere , becs i have these data which are unstructured , and finding paragraphs in these unstructured files are difficult or almost impossible. so i manage this from creating paragraph using a simple java program for counting number of lines from file (like generating random number assume 12, so first 12 lines will be first paragraph and so on...). i know this method is not a relevant and is not a solution for the asked questions but , it is managing with my projects. I thank to all for giving different suggestions to recover from this.

Answer (score -2):

In Windows a newline is represented by two characters "\r\n", or 0x0D0A in hexadecimal. Some systems(especially Unix) use "\n" only instead. So if a anything that begins on a newline is the start of a new paragraph, seriously, just count the number of "\n" characters...

Comment: Newline in Unix is represented by "\n".